# Simulate DFU on ATmega32A

Tags: atmega

I bought an ATmega32 to put it on a DIY keyboard kit. I uploaded a USB bootloader using Arduino as ISP and now I'm waiting for the keyboard PCB to mount the ATmega32A and flash QMK firmware on it using USB type C available on PCB.

My question: Could I simulate a USB firmware update using an FTDI programmer?
Doing that task on the KB kit requires to tap the reset button while holding the boot button to enable DFU mode. Which are the pins to use to do that directly on the ATmega32A?

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about the ATmega32A, and not the ATmega32U4, which has a USB interface?

Comment: @Velvel Yes, I'm sure! it is a ATmega32A pdip 40 pin. This is the kit https://github.com/coseyfannitutti/mysterium

Comment: the github page has a picture of the PCB ... you can follow the trace from switch to the ATmega32A ... if you have the board, then follow the trace on the board

Comment: @jsotola I guess that other ways exists. thinking that connecting the ftdi can simulate the update via usb is correct?

Comment: Surely which pins depends on which bootloader you programmed onto it?

Comment: @user253751 Actually I burnt the one provided by Arduino IDE

Comment: then it's probably designed for arduino IDE use I guess?

Comment: @user253751 that could be, but this not problem, eventualy I could burn the none provided by kit designer. Question is: how can I put ATmega32 in DFU mode? How can I connect FTDI TTL to ATMega32 to simulate firmare update via USB?